# Google Container Builder is unable to access private Github repositaries

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I have two private repositaries on Github, A and B. Both are Golang projects. Project A depends on repositary B. I have added both repositaries to Google Source Code.

Now in Container builder, when I try to build for project A, it is not able to access repositary B. In the build logs, I see:

```
Step #1: [0;33m[WARN]  [mUnable to checkout github.com/avi/api

Step #1: [0;31m[ERROR] [mUpdate failed for github.com/avi/api: Unable to get repository
```

How do I debug/fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not possible as of now:

> We don’t have an integrated solution as of today, but we have seen one solution coming from users. The trick is to use a Deploy or User Key that you could store in GCS for example, and pull it as a previous build step.

[github/cloud-builders](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/44#issuecomment-295334795)

Comment: You are correct that there is no integrated solution at this time, but yours is not the first use case we've seen where such a feature would be helpful. We are considering an integrated solution as part of the product offering...

Answer (score 0):

there is a solution now: [Accessing Private GitHub Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/access-private-github-repos)

(sorry for the link-only answer, feel free to edit this or post a better answer using the link)